# Choosing replacement seals for trailer hubs?

Tags: bearing, trailer, seal, hub

How do you know what seal to use as a replacement for a trailer hub?

When you replace the bearing it seems straightforward - the numbers on the existing  bearing can be used to pick a new one. But how do you know what seal is correct? Is there some kind of index or cross-reference to the bearing? Would the inside opening of the hub (bore) also have to be measured?

In my specific case my inner bearing is an 4t-lm48548 but I mean this to be more of a general-purpose question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would measure the diameter of where the seal locates, the depth available for the seal and the diameter of the shaft.

Any good seal selling place can match a seal with that along with the speed of the shaft and its duty ie hot liquid, grease etc

Those measurements need to be accurate, at least 1 decimal place.